# How to create a new command in a template to replace often used URLs

Tags: pdftex, templates, pandoc, links, markdown

I'm looking to create a new command in my LaTeX template where I can define a long url, so that if that URL changes, I can change it in one place rather than every place it appears. It would also make it a lot easier and cleaner to insert links to places.

I'm using Markdown with a LaTeX template, so what I have in my Markdown is something like:

```
[Google](www.google.com)
```

What I would like to be able to do is something like:

```
[Google](\google)
```

except where the link inside `\google` is a link that is used throughout many documents, is possibly quite long, and liable to change.

So far I have tried to add:

```
\newcommand{\google}{www.google.com} 
and used it like this in my test document
[Google](\google)
```

but this produces a link that is trying to link to `File:\\google.pdf`

Any ideas how I can make this into a regular link?

Comment: Can you provide an MWE please?

Comment: As far as i understand you have to use the `latex_macros` Extension, did you enable that extension? 
`Macro definitions in LaTeX will be passed through as raw LaTeX only if latex_macros is not enabled.`
https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html

Answer (score 1):

The comment as an answer:
You need to enable the `latex_macros` extension to have the macros evaluated. From the [Manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html)

> Macro definitions in LaTeX will be passed through as raw LaTeX only if latex_macros is not enabled.

To do this, use something like this: `pandoc test.tex --from markdown+latex_macros -o test.html`